# Is there any plugin to scan the available WIFI networks in Flutter Windows and Mac

Tags: flutter

I need to scan for available wifi networks from a Flutter Windows and a Mac Application,
There is plugin [wifi_scan](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_scan) but it only works for Android and iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developed a plugin to scan for available wifi networks that work on windows, working on adding support for Mac OS

https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_scan_windows